# How do I reference typescript from one local node project in another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have two node projects using typescript.

In one node project, I have a bunch of classes defined. In the other node project, I want to use and instantiate instance of these classes.

I have tried the following line...

```
import { MyClass } from "../../../my-other-project/src";
```

But it gives me the error...

```
Cannot find module '../../../my-other-project/src' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Comment: Are the two projects related? In short, I am asking if they can be arranged under a single mono repo/

Answer (score 0):

You could add the other project as local npm package with

```
npm install file:../../../my-other-project
```

Then it can be used with

```
import { MyClass } from "my-other-project";
```

You should avoid move the other project relative to this project after this.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract your shared classes to another project as a package and then use [npm Link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) to reference them locally. You can also commit your new package to GitHub and reference it from your package directly from a GitHub private repo.